# How do I fix the problem with "object not found" in R

Tags: r, variables, regression

Hello I am trying to define my variables but R cannot find them. I want to do polynomial regression with more than one independent variable. First I wanted to define them as x1 and x2 but R cannot find these variables. This is how it goes:

Before proceeding: I have imported the data as an excel file named as "R_DATA2" my dependent variable is "PM", my independent variables are "SO2" and "Temperature".

```
df <- R_DATA2
> summary(df)
       PM              SO2          Temperature    
 Min.   : 52.64   Min.   : 4.088   Min.   :-3.500  
 1st Qu.: 76.84   1st Qu.: 7.400   1st Qu.: 5.575  
 Median :105.68   Median : 9.266   Median :12.600  
 Mean   :118.62   Mean   :17.090   Mean   :12.688  
 3rd Qu.:158.02   3rd Qu.:15.073   3rd Qu.:20.925  
 Max.   :261.84   Max.   :75.270   Max.   :25.800  
> names(df)
[1] "PM"          "SO2"         "Temperature"
> class(SO2)
Hata: 'SO2' nesnesi bulunamadı
> exists("SO2")
[1] FALSE
>
```

Please help me. I am in desperate need.
Thank you so much.

Comment: `SO2` is a column in `df`. Its not it's own object. You can do something like `df$SO2` instead.

Comment: Thanks it worked. @MrFlick. You are the best.

Answer (score 0):

`exists` is by default checking the object created on on the global environment.  In the global env, there is no object named 'SO2'.  It exists only within the dataframe 'df' environment as a column We need to specify the `where`

```
exists("SO2", where = df)
```

---

Also, `with` is an option to get single or multiple column names

```
with(df, SO2)
with(df, SO2 + Temperature)
```

Comment: then if I want to name it as x1 do I have to type this: x1 <- SO2, where=df ? @akrun

Comment: sorry I accidentally hit the post button. Now it is complete

Comment: @DEFNESELENAKDEMİR If you want to create a new object, you can either use `$` or `[[` or `with` to extract as. a vector i.e. `x1 <- df[["SO2"]]` or `x1 <- df$SO2` or `x1 <- with(df, SO2)`

Comment: @DEFNESELENAKDEMİR the `exists` is to check whether that column is present in the datasets or not.  It returns a logical TRUE or FALSE as output